# P(D | w) vs P(y | x, w) - likelihood notation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

In certain ML books/lectures/slides/notes about Bayesian inference, you often see the likelihood written as $P(\mathcal{D} | w) = \Pi_{i \in N} P(y_i | x_i, w)$, where $\mathcal{D} = {(x_1, y_1),~ ...~,(x_n, y_n)}$. It then follows that the equation for Bayes rule is:

$$ P(w | \mathcal{D}) = \frac{P(\mathcal{D} | w) \cdot p(w)}{P(\mathcal{D})} $$

I'm confused because if you separate out the covariates from the response (inputs from targets), you could get the following equation for Bayes rule:

$$ P(w | x_i, y_i) = \frac{P(y_i | x_i, w) \cdot p(w | x_i)}{P(x_i, y_i)} $$

These two equations don't match up, in particular $p(w) \neq p(w | x_i)$. So what is the justification for this? In both a frequentist sense and a Bayesian sense?

I know that, for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function), defines the likehood function as the joint probability of the observed data, which would allow for this confusion to make sense. And when performing MLE, you maximize the response/targets in conjunction with the covariates/inputs, so it makes sense intuitively for this notation, but what would be the theoretical justification?

Edit:
I suppose I'm more confused by why would $P(y_i | x_i, w)$ have the same formulation for the likelihood function as $P(\mathcal{D} | w)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood in a parametric model is the joint density (or mass function) of the observed data conditional on any parameters in the model (which are treated as random in a Bayes context).

So using $f$ to denote a density or mass function, and letting $x$ denote the joint $x_i$ data, $y$ denote the joint $y_i$ data, and $\theta$ denote parameters, I would write the likelihood as

$$f(y,x|\theta)=f(y|x,\theta)f(x|\theta).$$

Note that if the density of $x$ doesn't depend on $\theta$, maximizing likelihood over the parameter space is equivalent to maximizing $f(y|x,\theta),$ since the density of $x$ just scales this up.

As far as using Bayes' rule, we have
$$f(\theta|y,x)=\frac{f(y,x|\theta)f(\theta)}{f(y,x)}=\frac{f(y|x,\theta)f(\theta|x)f(x)}{f(y,x)},$$

and often in a Bayesian context you will see this is written up to proportionality since other terms are simply normalizing constants (since $\theta$ is the random variable of interest):

$$f(\theta|y,x)\propto f(y,x|\theta)f(\theta)\propto f(y|x,\theta)f(\theta|x).$$

If you are confused at any point, just write out everything in terms of joint and marginal densities or masses to convince yourself of the correct identity. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Could you clarify the simplifying feature part of: "$f(x|\theta)$ does not depend on $\theta$, then likelihood, regarded as a function of $\theta$, is proportional to $f(y|x,\theta),$ which is a simplifying feature often in maximum likelihood estimation"?

Comment: Other than that, I think this mostly makes sense! But what abut the marginal of $f(x)$ in the numerator? Where does that usually go? Is it not expressed because we usually don't care about the marginal of $x$? Also, so then why would $f(y,x|\theta)$ be equivalent to $f(y|x,\theta)$? Say that $y$ is normally distributed, $f(y|x,\theta)$ would be optimized using MLE through squared error, but would $f(y|x,\theta)$ have the same formulation for a likelihood function?

Comment: @user2793618 Sorry for the confusion. Not my clearest answer:( As for your first comment, take a frequentist view for a second (treating $\theta $ as a constant)...MLE is a frequentist procedure anyway. What I meant is that we may often be given a conditional model for $y|x$ and also assume the density of $x$ doesn't depend on $\theta.$ For instance, think about the normal linear regression model $Y|X \sim N(X\beta,\sigma^2 I)$ where we also assume the density of $X$ typically doesn't depend on $\beta$.  This model justifies the OLS estimator as an MLE.

Comment: ...If the density of $X$ does depend on $\beta$, then one would have to include its density in the likelihood (which is the joint density of $x$ and $y$), which complicates estimation. Now what I wrote in my answer conditioned on the parameters just to be consistent with the Bayes framework in the next part of my answer.

Comment: So the density of $x$ always enters into the likelihood, but for purposes of MLE, if we believe its density doesn't depend on the parameters, it may be safely disregarded as it just scales the conditional density of $y|x$, which doesn't affect the optimization

Comment: I'll try to get back to your second comment later or maybe I will write another answer that is more clear when I am less sleepy

Comment: Thanks! That would be amazing :) I guess that makes sense, but even with fully Bayesian approaches (MCMC and such, e.g., stan), you define $P(\mathcal{D} | w)$ in the same way as $P(y_i | x_i, w)$

Comment: @user2793618 Missed getting back, but does it all make sense now? The proportionality part is not too essential by the way. However, if we want to figure out the posterior distribution (i.e. $\theta$ conditional on data $y,x$), we  can look at the posterior density up to proportionality to determine its parametric family since the stuff not depending on $\theta$ just scales the posterior density to make it integrate to one.

Comment: Yeah I get the proportionality. I am still a bit unsure of why the formulation of the likelihood of where $x_i$ is a condition would be the same when it's specified as part of the joint.

Comment: As mentioned above, $f(y,x|\theta)=f(y|x,\theta)f(x|\theta).$ So the objects $f(y,x|\theta)$ and $f(y|x,\theta)$ are **not** the same. My point was that if the density of $x$, which in a Bayesian context is written $f(x|\theta)$, has no dependency on $\theta$, then the $\theta^*$ that maximizes $f(y,x|\theta)$ is exactly the same as the $\theta^*$ that maximizes  $f(y|x,\theta).$

Comment: So **if** the density of $x$ doesn't depend on $\theta$, then you can solve for the MLE by maximizing $f(y|x,\theta)$

Comment: Could you expand on why $\theta*$ that maximises $f(y,x|\theta)$ is the same the $\theta*$ that maximises $f(y|x,\theta)$ if $x$ doesn't depend on $\theta$? I think this is making a lot more sense.

Comment: For constant $A>0$, the function $F(\theta)=AG(\theta)$ just scales the function $G(\theta)$ by a positive constant; thus, $F$ and $G$ are maximized at the same points.  Your setup is a special case of this rule where $F(\theta)=f(y,x|\theta),G(\theta)=f(y|x,\theta),A=f(x|\theta)$ if $f(x|\theta)>0$ doesn't depend on $\theta.$

Comment: Oh I see, you're treating $f(x|\theta)$ as a monotonic transformation. Hmm, but in many cases the distribution of $x$ is defined on negative values too, and this notation is still used.

Comment: No, $x$ may be negative, but its *density* is always nonnegative

Comment: Right ok, that makes sense then, thanks!

Comment: @user2793618 ok great!

Comment: Thanks for the help!